# How to add numbers together with IF statement in RACTIVE.js?

Tags: javascript

I am coding in Ractive for a school asignment, but i have a problem that i cannot solve.

I have the following loop:

```
{{#tasks:i}}
    {{#if sprintId == sprintURL}}
         {{estimatedTime}}, 
    {{/if}}
{{/tasks}}
```

This Outputs:

```
300,60,40,50,30,
```

What I need to do is add the numbers together to output a single total number.

I would like to just add the values to a variable, but that is not possible in Ractive.

Does anyone have a suggestion? I would really appriciate it.

Answer (score 0):

you have to sum up the values in your model. Keep logic out of your templates.